# gluUnProject always returns zero

Tags: android, opengl-es, coordinates

I need gluUnProject to convert screen coordinates to world coordinates and right now I just about have it working.  When my app runs it accurately tells me the coordinates on screen which I know are stored in my renderer thread and then pumps out screen coordinates. Unfortunately the screen coordinates seem to have no effect of world coordinates and the world coordinates remain at zero.

Here is my gluUnProject method

```
public void vector3 (GL11 gl){

        int[] viewport = new int[4];
        float[] modelview = new float[16];
        float[] projection = new float[16];
        float winx, winy, winz;
        float[] newcoords = new float[4];

        gl.glGetIntegerv(GL11.GL_VIEWPORT, viewport, 0);
        ((GL11) gl).glGetFloatv(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview, 0);
        ((GL11) gl).glGetFloatv(GL11.GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection, 0);

        winx = (float)setx;
        winy = (float)viewport[3] - sety;
        winz = 0;

        GLU.gluUnProject(setx, (float)viewport[3] - sety, 0, modelview, 0, projection, 0, viewport, 0, newcoords, 0);
        posx = (int)newcoords[0];
        posy = (int)newcoords[1];
        posz = (int)newcoords[2];



        Log.d(TAG, "x= " + String.valueOf(posx));
        Log.d(TAG, "y= " + String.valueOf(posy));
        Log.d(TAG, "z= " + String.valueOf(posz));
        }
```

Now I've searched and found [this forum post](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?91548-gluUnProject) and they came to the conclusion that it was to do with using getFloatv instead of getDoublev, but getDoublev does not seem to be supported by GL11

```
The method glGetDoublev(int, float[], int) is undefined for the type GL11
```

and also

```
The method glGetDoublev(int, double[], int) is undefined for the type GL11
```

should the double and float thing matter and if so how do I go about using doubles

Thank you

**EDIT:**

I was told that gluUnproject fails when too close to the near far clipping plane so I set winz to -5 when near is 0 and far is -10.  This had no effect on the output.

I also logged each part of the newcoords[] array and they all return something that is NaN (not a number) could this be the problem or something higher up in the algorithm

Comment: Regarding you edit, `winz` has to be in [0,1], with 0 representing the near plane and 1 representing the far plane.

Comment: @Christian Rau  Do you mean between 0 and 1?

Comment: Yes, but inclusive. winz has to be in [0,1], not neccessarily (0,1). I'm not sure why it should fail if winz is too near to the clipping planes?

Comment: I just heard that from somewhere maybe that was an unusual error

Comment: And the matrices you're retrieving are really the ones you used to render the data with?

Comment: I hope so what other alternative matrices are there

Comment: You just have to keep in mind that these functions retrieve the matrices that are ontop of the repsective stacks at the moment you call them.

Comment: Well this method is called at the bottom of the draw method (which probably isn't to economic but I couldn't think how else to do it).

Comment: Actually the near and far plane don't need to be in [0-1] range as OpenGL takes care of that normalization when projecting. They however both need to be positive and the near plane z needs to be smaller than the far plane z.

Comment: Hmm just thinking if my phone uses a version of opengl that is newer than the version i've targeted my app at, does it run emulated?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're working on the emulator? Its OpenGL implementation is rather buggy, and after testing I found that it returns all zeroes for the following calls:

```
gl11.glGetIntegerv(GL11.GL_VIEWPORT, viewport, 0);
gl11.glGetFloatv(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview, 0);
gl11.glGetFloatv(GL11.GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection, 0);
```

The `gluUnProject`() function needs to calculate the inverse of the combined modelview-projection matrix, and since these are all zeroes, the inverse does not exist and will consist of NaNs. The resulting `newcoords` vector is therefor also all Nans.

Try it on a device with a proper OpenGL implementation, it should work. Keep in mind to still divide by `newcoords[3]` though ;-)

Comment: Unfortunatley I'm working on a real 2.2 device =/ LG Optimus Black

Comment: Sorry its been a while since you answered my question but i've just thought. I'm writing in opengl 1.0 but my phone runs 2.0 Doesn't that mean that the code is running in some sort of emulator on the phone. Maybe that's why I'm getting zeros because it actually is running in an emulator like you said.

Comment: I wouldn't expect that, usually ES1.1 functionality is built on top of the 2.0 implementation in the driver. You can easily check what implementation you're using, by looking at what glGetString() returns for GL_VERSION, GL_RENDERER and GL_VENDOR.